# Double ended priority queue

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a set of data and I want to find the biggest and smallest items (multiple times), what's the best way to do this?

For anyone interested in the application, I'm developing a level of detail system and I need to find the items with the biggest and smallest screen space error, obviously every time I subdivide/merge an item I have to insert it into the queue but every time the camera moves the entire dataset changes - so it might be best to just use a sorted list and defer adding new items until the next time I sort (since it happens so often)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Min-Max Heap as described in the paper [Min-Max Heaps and Generalized Priority Queues](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/mike/Papers/MinMaxHeaps/MinMaxHeaps.pdf):

> A simple implementation of
>   double ended priority queues is
>   presented. The proposed structure,
>   called a min-max heap, can be built in
>   linear time; in contrast to
>   conventional heaps, it allows both
>   FindMin and FindMax to be performed in
>   constant time; Insert, DeleteMin, and
>   DeleteMax operations can be performed
>   in logarithmic time.